# How to get the value of submitted option of django_filters in view?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a django application where I am using django-filter to filter my data https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter . The documentation tells us how to display options in django filter but no where it says that when the user submits an option, how do I get that submitted option value in views.py so i can use it in other functions. Here is my code:

```
def knowledge_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        knowledgefilterform = KnowledgeFilter(request.POST)
        if knowledgefilterform.is_valid():
            data = knowledgefilterform.cleaned_data
            if data['knowledgebase_id']:
                knowledges = Knowledge.objects.filter(knowledgebase_id=data['knowledgebase_id'])
    else:
       knowledges = Knowledge.objects.all()
    knowledgefilter = KnowledgeFilter( queryset=Knowledgebase.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    return render(request, 'knowledge_list.html',{'knowledges':knowledges, 'knowledgefilter': knowledgefilter  })
```

I was trying to get the value using cleaned_data just like other forms but it gives me error saying that is_valid() is an invalid attribute for django-filter. So how do I get the value of option submitted by the user?

Comment: Does `KnowledgeFilter` inherit from a Django `Form` class? I haven't used this package, but what I would do to figure out how to get the values is put a breakpoint at the top of the view function with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, and then inspect the `KnowledgeFilter` object. At the pdb prompt (which will show up in the console where you're running the dev server, you could execute `dir(knowledgefilterform)` after you have created your instance, and see what attributes it has, or do the same thing with `print`s, or look at the source of whatever `KnowledgeFilter` inherits from. Good luck!